# How can I get new page likes on facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku, realtime-api

I'm trying to get new user likes on page which is attached to my facebook application. I have added Webhooks product, then I had set my callback url to Heroku app. I can get test feedback but when I'm trying to get real feedback then I can't do this. Is there any possible way to take this likes without generating page access token?

Comment: No, you can not subscribe for any page updates via webhook without a page access token.

Comment: Okey, thanks for help.